# Using std::transform to Add Vector of Vectors (A) to another Vector of Vectors (B)

Tags: c++, vector, sum, overloading, addition

I'm quite new to using vectors and coding C++ in general and still haven't fully grasped the language yet. My inquiries are as follows:

    1.  My main problem seems to be my *transform* line, why is that so?
    2. How do I print the vector sums of A and B?

3. How do I overload the [][] operator for access and make it work? (i.e. the code should still work if Mat[1][3] = 4 is written)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
public:
    double x;
    vector<vector<double> > I{ { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };

    vector<vector<double> > Initialization(vector<vector<double> > I, double x);
    vector<vector<double> > Copy(vector<vector<double> > I);
    void Print(vector<vector<double> > I);

};

vector<vector<double> > Matrix::Initialization(vector<vector<double> > I, double x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < I.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < I[i].size(); j++)
        {
            // new matrix 
            I[i][j] *= x;
        }
    }
    return I;
};

vector<vector<double> > Matrix::Copy(vector<vector<double> > I)
{
    vector<vector<double> > I_copy = I;
    return I_copy;
};

void Matrix::Print(vector<vector<double> > I)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < I.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < I[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << I[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Matrix m;
    vector<vector<double> > A;
    vector<vector<double> > B;

    cin >> m.x;

    A = m.Initialization(m.I, m.x);
    B = m.Copy(A);

    m.Print(A);
    m.Print(B);


    B.resize(A.size());


    transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), A.begin(), plus<double>());

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you can be patient in helping me fix my code and letting me understand why my syntax is incorrect and uncompilable. Thank you so much <3

Comment: One question by question.

Comment: Did you try `m.Print(A)` after the transform? Was the matrix transformed?

Comment: You would need `plus<vector<double>>()` which is not valid.

Comment: "My main problem seems to be my transform line, why is that so?" I have no idea what this question means.  It reads like "Why is Earth?"; it is formed like a question, but not a sensible one.

Comment: Are these the correct iterators? **transform(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), plus<double>());**

Answer (score 0):

As Jarod42 notes in the comments, you need something that adds `std::vector<double>`s, as well as something that adds `double`s.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> lhs, const std::vector<T> & rhs)
{
    std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), [](const T & a, const T & b){ return a + b; });
    return lhs;
}
```

Note that we take a copy of the left hand side, but only reference the right hand side. This also gives us somewhere to write the result to.

The usage is then very simple

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > A { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } };
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > B { { 1, 0 }, { 0, 1 } };
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > C { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 1 } };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (A + B == C) << std::endl;
}
```

[See it live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee48a537a9af6838)